# How can I use the CSS :target selector to create a reusable modal box

Tags: html, css

I have a large collection of proverbs from an endangered language and I'd like to use a modal box for each to make different transcriptions available, without cluttering the page. I've created a div element that expands to show the optional information when clicked on using the CSS :target selector, and I'd like to be able to use that code over and over again for each proverb without creating an unique class or ID for each proverb. The problem is that clicking on a proverb in the middle of the list only expands the first div box. Is there a way to get the div box to open for each proverb that's clicked on without creating a unique expandable div for each proverb (I have hundreds of them)?

Here's the code I used:

```css
#modalBox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#modalBox:target {
  height: 13.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="proverbs">
  <div id="modalBox">
    <a href="#modalBox"> A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</a>
    <p id="data"><b>IPA:</b> a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</p>
    <p id="data"><b>Italian:</b> La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</p>
    <p id="data"><b>English:</b> The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</p>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="modalclose">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This remind me of a recent question: [Why my page jumps to top, how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777802/why-my-page-jumps-to-top-how-can-i-prevent-it/).
And my answer was not to use `:target` selector. It messes with the #hash of the page causing side effects. I prefer JavaScript. BTW, the question seems to be a similar problem like yours so check it out.

Comment: @ITgoldman OP's question is about code reusability—not page jump issues with `:target`.

Comment: The Tidy button in the snippet editor revealed an extra closing paragraph tag in your markup.

Comment: You can use an id prefix and count the elements: `[id^=modalBox]:target` and then just number the ids: `#modalBox1` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several **CSS**-first approaches to producing this effect (which do without javascript mostly or entirely).

But *one* approach barely relies even on **CSS**: it's an **HTML**-first solution.

The `details / summary` pair of elements are the perfect semantic markup for presenting this kind of information.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.modalBox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: min(98%, 800px);
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modalBox summary {
  font-style: italic;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalBox p {
  transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.modalBox[open] p {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="proverbs">
  <details class="modalBox">
    <summary> A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</summary>
    <p data-lang="ipa"><b>IPA:</b> a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</p>
    <p data-lang="it"><b>Italian:</b> La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</p>
    <p data-lang="en"><b>English:</b> The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</p>
  </details>
  
  <details class="modalBox">
    <summary> A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</summary>
    <p data-lang="ipa"><b>IPA:</b> a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</p>
    <p data-lang="it"><b>Italian:</b> La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</p>
    <p data-lang="en"><b>English:</b> The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</p>
  </details>
  
  <details class="modalBox">
    <summary> A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</summary>
    <p data-lang="ipa"><b>IPA:</b> a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</p>
    <p data-lang="it"><b>Italian:</b> La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</p>
    <p data-lang="en"><b>English:</b> The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</p>
  </details>
</div>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary
- https://css-tricks.com/two-issues-styling-the-details-element-and-how-to-solve-them/

Comment: I would have suggested `details`/`summary` as well, but there's no way to animate it.

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you! It's at my skill level and I'm able to fetch audio and other data into the summary and details sections using PhP. One question though; why use the 'data-lang="ipa"' selector instead of assigning the p element an ID? I'm not familiar with this. How would I stylize these p's in my CSS sheet?

Comment: I'm very happy this approach is the kind of thing you were looking for. Two reasons for `data-lang` - 1) we can't use the same `id` on more than a single element in a single document. An `id` is, effectively, a _unique identifier_; 2) since you had used `id="data"`, I concluded you would want the document to have some awareness that the `<summary>` represented _data_ so I took the liberty of applying the custom data `lang` and using an appropriate abbreviation for each value.

Comment: To select an element with a custom data attribute in CSS, you can use... `p[data-lang="en"]` to select a specific element, or `p[data-lang]` to select _any_ element with a `data-lang` custom data attribute.

Comment: For more info on custom data attributes, see: [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Is there any reason why when using this approach, the audio on the first proverb would work and the others no? I used a mysqli statement to fetch the data into the details/summary box. Everything worked great except for the audio: https://memoriaelinguagrumentina.org/proverbs/proverbs.php

Comment: It's probably worth starting a new question to ask that. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could do this cleanly without at least *some* JavaScript. Here is a vanilla implementation to get you started. Instead of targeting precise `id`s, we can use a `class` name instead, and let the interpreter figure out which `id` is the clicked one.

The JavaScript runs through the HTML, dynamically adding incrementing `id`s (e.g., `modalBox0`, `modalBox1`, etc.) and the corresponding link which opens each modal (e.g., `href='#modalBox0'`, `href='#modalBox1'`, etc.).

```js
const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modalBox');

modals.forEach((modal, index) => {
  const id = `modalBox${index}`;
  modal.id = id
  const link = modal.querySelector('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', `#${id}`)
})
```

```css
.modalBox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.modalBox:target {
  height: 13.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="proverbs">
  <div class="modalBox">
    <a href="#"> A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</a>
    <p id="data"><b>IPA:</b> a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</p>
    <p id="data"><b>Italian:</b> La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</p>
    <p id="data"><b>English:</b> The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</p>
    <a href="#" class="modalclose">&times;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="modalBox">
    <a href="#"> A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</a>
    <p id="data"><b>IPA:</b> a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</p>
    <p id="data"><b>Italian:</b> La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</p>
    <p id="data"><b>English:</b> The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</p>
    <a href="#" class="modalclose">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dr1jn5w/)

Comment: A `NodeList` (the result of `querySelectorAll`) has [a `forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), so there's no need for `Array.from`... Also, it would be easier to use `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll()[0]`, IMO.

Comment: Why `modal.querySelectorAll('a')[0]` instead of simply `modal.querySelector('a')`?

Comment: Thank you, I could try this, but I was trying to make the CSS only approach work, because I know very little javascript. Also, I've been using PhP to fetch audio files for each proverb and I'm not sure how to make PhP and javascript work on the same page.

Comment: @HereticMonkey For posterity. I made those adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

With 100+ proverbs you'll need JavaScript. This example takes an array of objects and inserts the content when the user either clicks the `#next` or `#back` `<button>`. The only thing you need to change is the data:

```js
const proverbs = [
  {
    main: `A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.`,
    ipa: `a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ`,
    it: `La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.`,
    en: `The hasty cat makes blind kittens.`
  },...
];
/*
Structure is [{main: 'first line', ipa: 'line of ipa', it: 'line of Italian',
 en: 'line of English'}, {second proverb}, {third proverb},...]
*/
```

Although it uses `#id` because the [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) interface uses `#id`, `[name]`, or index references -- I used `#id` because the CSS selector is easier to write. There is just a single modal that handles an unlimited amount of those 4 lined proverbs, so `#id` shouldn't be a problem and if they are you can use `[name]` attribute instead.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const UI = document.forms.UI;
// Array of proverbs and translations
const proverbs = [
  {main: `A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.`,
   ipa: `a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ`,
   it: `La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.`,
   en: `The hasty cat makes blind kittens.`},
   {main: `010101010101010101010101010101010101010101`, ipa: `02`, it: `03`, en: `04`},
   {main: `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`, ipa: `12`, it: `13`, en: `14`},
   {main: `2121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121`, ipa: `22`, it: `23`, en: `24`},
   {main: `3131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131`, ipa: `32`, it: `33`, en: `34`},
   {main: `4141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141`, ipa: `42`, it: `43`, en: `44`},
   {main: `5151515151515151515151515151515151515151515151`, ipa: `52`, it: `53`, en: `54`}
];
// Define counter
let count = 0; 
// Bind <form> to the click event
UI.onclick = clickHandler;
// Event handler passes Event Object by default
function clickHandler(e) {
  // Reference <dialog>
  const modal = document.querySelector('.proverbs');
  // Reference what the user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // reference all <button>s and the <fieldset>
  const IO = this.elements;
  // If the user clicked #open, open <dialog>
  if (clk.matches('#open')) {
    clk.style.display = 'none';
    modal.showModal();
  }
  // If the user clicked #close, close <dialog>
  if (clk.matches('#close')) {
    IO.open.style.display = 'inline-flex';
    modal.close();
  }
  /*
  If the user clicked #next...
  ...increment count...
  ...if count is more than the total length of proverbs array...
  ...make count 0 (loop over to the start)...
  ...call move() pass count and IO
  */
  if (clk.matches('#next')) {
    ++count;
    if (count > (proverbs.length-1)) count = 0;
    move(count, IO);
  }
  // For the sake of brevity - it's the opposite of #next
  if (clk.matches('#back')) {
    --count;
    if (count < 0) count = proverbs.length -1;
    move(count, IO);
  }
}
// Pass in the counter and form control reference (IO) 
function move(i, fc) {
  // Reference <ul>
  const list = document.querySelector('.list');
  // htmlString of <legend> with new content
  const main = `<legend>${proverbs[i].main}</legend>`;
  // htmlstring of the new content of <ul>
  const items = `
        <li><b>IPA: </b>${proverbs[i].ipa}</li>
        <li><b>Italian: </b>${proverbs[i].it}</li>
        <li><b>English: </b>${proverbs[i].en}</li>`;
  // Remove the old <legend> and <li>
  fc.content.firstElementChild.remove();
  list.replaceChildren();
  // Insert the htmlStrings
  fc.content.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', main);
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', items);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');

html {
  font: 500 2ch/1.2 'Oswald'
}

dialog {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, 
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
}

#content {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

legend {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px outset rgb(227, 227, 227);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: inherit;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  float: right;
}

#back {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

#next {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <button id='open' type='button'>Open</button>
  <dialog class="proverbs">
    <button id="close" type='button'>&times;</button>
    <fieldset id='content'>
      <legend>A (g)attë mbrèšarolë facë i (g)attarièddë cëcatë.</legend>
      <ul class='list'>
        <li><b>IPA: </b>a atːə mˌbɾɪʃəˈɾolə fat͡ʃ i ˈatːaɾiˌɛdːə t͡ʃə katʰ</li>
        <li><b>Italian: </b>La gatta frettolosa fa i gattini ciechi.</li>
        <li><b>English: </b>The hasty cat makes blind kittens.</li>
      </ul>
      <button id='next' class='btn' type='button'>Next</button>
      <button id='back' class='btn' type='button'>Back</button>
    </fieldset>
  </dialog>
</form>
```